# Segmentation fault during processing delete command

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

I have a program that using a vector (called _library) that holds objects of the class 'thread' that I've created (holds a set of data, and allocating some stuff in its Constructor).

Now, I've tried to run my program, calling this line:

```
delete (_library[_currRunning]);
```

->and got the scary Segmentation fault message from my compiler.

I don't understand what is the problem here, since I perform boundary checks, and - what's more surprising: it works on other inputs, when I've tested it before!

In general, what can cause a segmentation fault when using 'delete', and how could I prevent such errors in my code?

In addition, I have a destructor for the 'thread' class, having this single line:

```
delete (_stack);
```

where _stack is a char* that I've allocated in the Ctor.

Here're my 'thread' object fields:

```
char* _stack;  
int _tid;  
void (*_thread_func)(void);  
sigjmp_buf _jbuf;  
Sync* _sync;  
int _status;
```

In 'thread' Ctor, there is (between others) this line:

```
_stack = new char[STACK_SIZE];
```

And this is its Dtor:

```
delete[] _stack;
```

In my big program, i have this declaration:

```
vector<thread*> _library;
```

Is there any problem of using 'delete' inside my Destructor, instead of using 'free'?

Comment: what is the exact type of `_library`?  Obviously, you're not deleting `thread` objects directly.  Also, it would be very helpful if you could give us the stack trace when the segfault occurs.

Comment: You need to post much more code than this.

Comment: You still missed the important part. How the vector `_library` is filled with `thread*` objects and deallocating it. As you said, segmentation fault is occuring by this - `delete (_library[_currRunning]);`

Comment: I get the impression that you are not a veteran software engineer.  At least you're not familiar with C++ development.  And yet it looks like you're trying to write your own thread library.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming _libray[_currRunning] contains a pointer, either:

1. `_library[_currRunning]` is an invalid address
2. `_library[_currRunning]` has already been deleted

If it's the second case, make sure you remove the element from the vector (using `erase`) after you delete it.

**EDIT:** By "invalid", I mean the address to an object that wasn't created with `new`.

Comment: For later use in my program, i do not want to use erase, but to save NULL instead in its place. (I know that's not nice, but it simplify my code in a great deal)

Comment: Then set `_library[_currRunning]` to `NULL`. `delete` on a null pointer is guaranteed to be a no-op. However, make sure you don't call a method on the null pointer afterwards: terrible things will happen.

Comment: But then the stack (char*) that i've allocated inside my thread won't be freed if i don't use delete, will it?

Comment: If you call `delete` on your thread, it will call the thread's destructor, which deletes the `_stack`

Comment: @spbots That's why i've tried to deallocate the thread's stack using 'delete' on the thread objects, but that appears to not working..

Answer (score 1):

With the very little info you've provided I would assume that you are double freeing one of the thread objects.  Your problem is not with `vector` but with your lifetime management of the threads.

Answer (score 1):

if you allocated _stack like so:

```
_stack = new char[SOME_LEN];
```

you want to delete it with

```
delete[] _stack;
```

note the [] after delete that's needed when you allocate an array.

Comment: @Shoshke - Show more code of what you are doing. Check what is the `size` of the vector and the value of `_currRunning`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `delete` any objects of a vector- it will clean them up itself. Likely, you meant to use `vector.erase()` to remove it.

Comment: I doubt that's the problem: if the vector contains pointers, then `delete` is likely to be needed. If the vector contains values, it won't even compile.

Comment: My declaration is as follows: vector<thread*> _library; Will it call thread's Dtor when finishing the program?

Comment: @Shoshke - No, it won't call. You need to explicitly deallocate the resources if the vector is of type `std::vector<thread*>`

Answer (score 0):

Unless your `_currRunning` is a pointer created at some point with new, delete will have repercussions. E.g.

```
void func()
{
   int a = 1;
   int* b = new int(2);
   delete b; // Ok, deleting a pointer
   delete a; // Can't delete non-pointer - should be a compilation error (?)
   delete &a; // This will call the destructor of a, but then the program 
              // will segfault when a goes out of scope at the end of this function.
}
```

Comment: Is there any problem of using 'delete' inside my Destructor, instead of using 'free'?